# "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified module could not be found." on jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

That's the error i get when i try and use the jupyter notebook, i've already tried several methods from posts on this site, but none of them seem to work; i tried uninstalling and reinstalling win32api, updating jupyter, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: How do you reinstall win32api? If you use the base environment, maybe it will work